# Is it possible to call a function within another function with the code below?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So my main goal here is to take in a 2D array of multiple student arrays and return an array of properly-formatted emails. I've tried to do `studentArr[i]` but that only gives me the final array of whatever is inside the 2D array. I'm now wondering if there is a way to call function getEmail within the getEmails function to reuse it?

```js
//first function 
function getEmail(studentArr) {
  //number extraction 
  const firstName = studentArr[0]; // extract first name
  const lastLetter = studentArr[1].substring(0, 1); // extracts first letter of last name 
  const last4num = studentArr[2].substring(5, 9); // last four 
  var email = firstName + lastLetter + last4num + "@school.org";
  return email.toLowerCase();
}
const listOne =getEmail(["Donia", "Abdelhalim", "956165171"])
console.log(listOne)
//"doniaa5171@school.org"

// second function 
function getEmails(studentsArr) {

  for (i = 0; i < studentsArr.length; i++) {
    // var firstLastDigit = studentsArr[i]; 
    let result = studentsArr;

  }
  return getEmail(result);
}
console.log(getEmails(listOne));

var listOne = [
  ["Donia","Abdelhalim","956165171"],
  ["Mohammed","Amin","756207074"],
  ["Sebastian","Andrade","935334038"],
  ["Anabel","Arbeeny","963558175"],
  ["Yuhang","Chen","896676447"],
  ["Victoria","Feng","233878175"],
  ["Kasper","Gacek","523387963"],
  ["Jeffrey","Guan","398396281"],
  ["Arieta","Haskaj","496044907"],
  ["Xavier","Jiang","963144620"]
 ];
```

Comment: You should map the array into the new array.  `studentArr.map(it => getEmail(it))`

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it to make a [mcve] - I added listOne but your still have errors - this is not correct `let result = studentsArr;`

Comment: How come I cant do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
//first function
function getEmail(studentArr) {
  //number extraction
  const firstName = studentArr[0]; // extract first name
  const lastLetter = studentArr[1].substring(0, 1); // extracts first letter of last name
  const last4num = studentArr[2].substring(5, 9); // last four
  var email = firstName + lastLetter + last4num + "@school.org";
  return email.toLowerCase();
}

// second function
function getEmails(studentsArr) {
  return studentsArr.map((stud)=>(getEmail(stud)));
}

var listOne = [
  ["Donia","Abdelhalim","956165171"],
  ["Mohammed","Amin","756207074"],
  ["Sebastian","Andrade","935334038"],
  ["Anabel","Arbeeny","963558175"],
  ["Yuhang","Chen","896676447"],
  ["Victoria","Feng","233878175"],
  ["Kasper","Gacek","523387963"],
  ["Jeffrey","Guan","398396281"],
  ["Arieta","Haskaj","496044907"],
  ["Xavier","Jiang","963144620"]
 ];

console.log(getEmails(listOne));
```

// Output
["doniaa5171@school.org", "mohammeda7074@school.org", "sebastiana4038@school.org",
"anabela8175@school.org", "yuhangc6447@school.org", "victoriaf8175@school.org",
"kasperg7963@school.org", "jeffreyg6281@school.org", "arietah4907@school.org",
"xavierj4620@school.org"]

Answer (score 0):

```js
//first function 
function getEmail(studentArr) {
    //number extraction 
    if (!studentArr) return null;
    const firstName = studentArr[0]; // extract first name
    const lastLetter = studentArr[1].substring(0, 1); // extracts first letter of last name 
    const last4num = studentArr[2].substring(5, 9); // last four 
    var email = firstName + lastLetter + last4num + "@school.org";
    return email.toLowerCase();
}

var listOne = [
    ["Donia", "Abdelhalim", "956165171"],
    ["Mohammed", "Amin", "756207074"],
    ["Sebastian", "Andrade", "935334038"],
    ["Anabel", "Arbeeny", "963558175"],
    ["Yuhang", "Chen", "896676447"],
    ["Victoria", "Feng", "233878175"],
    ["Kasper", "Gacek", "523387963"],
    ["Jeffrey", "Guan", "398396281"],
    ["Arieta", "Haskaj", "496044907"],
    ["Xavier", "Jiang", "963144620"]
];

function getEmails(listOne) {
    let emails = []
    listOne.forEach(student => {
        const email = getEmail(student)
        emails.push(email)
    })
    return emails;
}

const emails = getEmails(listOne)

console.log(emails)
```

you can Copy this code

Comment: Please provide some details regarding your solution.

Comment: getEmails will create an empty Array named emails, and then loops through listOne generating an email for each item in listOne and then push email into emails Array. And finally return emails as Array.